# Graph API - Update existing User - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, msal-angular

I am currently developing an app that communicates with the Graph API. I don't have any Backend, only a SPA. I use the npm package **@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client**.

The app should be able to change givenName, surname of an AD user.

At the beginning i create a new AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider instance and use it with the graph client, i'm not sure if the used scope is correct:

```
 const authProvider = new AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider(
        this.msalService.instance as PublicClientApplication,
        {
          account: this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount()!,
          scopes: ['User.ReadWrite.All'],
          interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        }
      );

 this.graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({
        authProvider: authProvider,
        defaultVersion: 'beta',
      });
```

My call looks like this

```
 const result = await this.authService.graphClient
        .api(`/users/${userId}`)
        .patch({
          givenName: firstname,
          surname: lastname
        });
```

However, I get an "Insufficient privileges" error message.

```
Could not update user with id 8639e42f-de7f-485a-9b18-ccd67d7b0146 {
  "statusCode": 403,
  "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
  "requestId": "xy",
  "date": "2022-02-03T11:45:48.000Z",
  "body": "{\"code\":\"Authorization_RequestDenied\",\"message\":\"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2022-02-03T12:45:48\",\"request-id\":\"xy\",\"client-request-id\":\"xy\"}}"
}
```

I have set the following permissions (under "Enterprise applications"):[image]

API Permissions (under "App registrations"):
[image]

Comment: What authentication method are you using ? is it Service Principal Credentials ?

Comment: Or is it implicit or auth code flow ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT implicit flow

Comment: have you granted the added permissions admin consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please make sure you have granted the Delegated Permission Admin Consent .**

***I tested the same using `implicit flow` where I created a Azure AD application and provided the `Delegated Permission` like below without granting admin consent :***

[image]

[image]

***After granting the Admin Consent the problem was fixed like below :***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i already granted the Delegated Permission Admin Consent (under "API Permissions"), but it doesn't work. have I forgotten something ? I have updated my posting above with my "API Permissions" settings.

Comment: If implicit flow is being used then the admin consented delegated permission should suffice .. if the scope for access token is set `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` but if client credentials is used the application permissions is required.

Comment: @pbachman, can you try giving application permission for user.readwrite.all?

Comment: Also make sure you are using correct client Id while generating the access token using your mail .

Comment: i use the MSAL Library from Microsoft (see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and i'm not sure, if i use the right scope. i updated my posting above with my MSAL code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check permissions reference here, to set the right scope : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

You have to notice that ["In delegated scenarios, the effective permissions granted to your app are constrained by the privileges of the signed-in user in the organization."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#microsoft-graph-permission-names)

If your app is a daemon (back end service without human interaction) [you should use "Application permission" instead of "Delegated permission"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps#permission-types).

You can choose the right authentication provider and the right permission type, based on scenario here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript

PS : you should hide the status column of your second screen shot, as it shows private information.

Comment: i already set the right "Delegated permissions". I don't have any Backend, only a SPA, thats why i I have used the following example as a guide (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=angular2) And thanks for the hint, i removed all private information ;-)